# Spelling assist in Idea-Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

While writing Java doc, if we are making any spelling mistakes Idea IntelliJ shows that there is a typo, but is there any way to do some settings so that it also shows possible correct words for that typo?

Thanks in advance.
Kitty

Comment: You can press `Alt` + `Enter` on the mistake and choose "Typo:Change to..."

Comment: Hi Vic, I tried that but it doesn't show the list of words which can be used.      Do I have to do some settings like linking dictionary to idea?